# WCF Service Reference.cs method giving error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, static-methods, service-reference

I see this question many times and understand I need to add static to the original method declaration. The problem is this is not a method I control. In my C# code, I've added a Service Reference. It's SOAP (XML) API. It's not my API. The compiler error is on a WCF void method in Reference.cs that I call in my program.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Console.ThirdPartyService;

namespace Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // New Third Party Service Client
            ThirdPartyServiceClient client = new ThirdPartyServiceClient();

            // Set user email address
            // Method is type void.
            // Compiler generates object reference error for non-static method.
            client.SetEMail("test@example.com");
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference.cs**

```
...
public void SetEmail(string email) {
    base.Channel.SaveUserInfo(email);
}
...
```

Let's presume the service provider will not update their API to resolve, if that's the solution. How else could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry. I see the issue. The code above is correct. I forgot to instantiate a client class which calls the method. It works now. If there are no objections, I'll go ahead and delete this question.